# Magento Page 404 Not Found 1 in checkout/onepage 1.6.0.0

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.5

I can not override the controller. In version 1.5 works but does not work in version 1.6.

```
<Rewrite>
       <! - Override the controllers OnePageCheckout ->
       <Mage_Mymodule_onepage>
         <from> <! [CDATA [# ^ / checkout / onepage #]]></ from>
         <to> / Mage_Mymodule / onepage / </ to>
         <override_actions> false </ override_actions>
       </ Mage_Mymodule_onepage>
</ rewrite>
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code :

```
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <onepage>
                <to>your_module_name/onepage</to>
                <override_actions>true</override_actions>
                <actions>
                    <action_name>
                        <to>your_module_name/onepage/action_name</to>
                    </action_name>
                </actions>
            </onepage>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
```

Here, 'action_name' is the function name in your OnepageController.php file.

Hope this helps!